# Programmatically replace UITableViewController by UIViewController with tableView inside via Button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I know the title is a bit weird, but I try to replace the `UITableViewController` by the `UIViewController` with following code:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let newController = JobTableViewController()
    self.navigationController?.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But every time I click on this Button I get following Error in my `ViewController` at this code line

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Comment: If you are using storyboard then you need to connect `tableView` in `storyboard`. If programmatically, you need to initialize it before accessing it.

Comment: Where in the viewController is the `tableView.delegate = self` written?

Comment: @Abizern inside the ViewDidLoad, but I got it working now, so nevermind, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
let newController = JobTableViewController()
```

do

```
let newController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VcId") as! JobTableViewController
```

Your vc is in stroryboard , you can't use `JobTableViewController()` only when the VC is created programmatically , don't forget to give the VC identifier in IB here **VcId**

Comment: Through this its giving me following error *Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)*